# How to cache an image from URL before displaying it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, caching

Basically, this app should contain a collection of objects in a view showing a representative image of each object (i.e. a movie should show its poster).

Talking about movies, I am trying to use the IMDB APIs in order to retrieve the metadata for a certain movie title, including its poster. However, hotlinking won't let me display the images once their URLs are obtained from the APIs (I keep getting the "GET [...] 403 Forbidden" error...).

Since I am using the JSONStore feature in order to cache the data, I would like to know if there is a possibility to store those images in JSONStore and then display them like a normal browser would do. I am trying to do all this sort of things from the front-end side, not the back-end one, using AngularJS, HTML5 and JavaScript.

Do you have any suggestions for this kind of problems?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested solution: What you'd need to do is to encode the images to base64 and this way you could store the binary image as a string inside your JSONStore collection.

When you then need to display it you will need to base64 decode the string back into an image and display it in your HTML

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Since the image element is obtained dynamically using AngularJS, when should this conversion take place? At the moment, image sources are retrieved from the external APIs using javascript, and then rendered as "ng-src" attributes.

Comment: Ah, my suggestion would've been better had the retrieval was being done using adapters I suppose.

Comment: Adapters force you to have the application deployed to a WebSphere Application server. As this is not my case, I was looking for a straight front-end solution avoiding the use of adapters. If I were able to use them, I would have done this thing using Java instead. :-)

Comment: MobileFirst apps are typically deployed to the MobileFirst Server, enabling you access to most of its capabilities. If you are not using anything MobileFirst per-se, this is not an IBM MobileFirst question.

Comment: It's just a web app that happened to be developed with MobileFirst, but in the context of your question, nothing is MobileFirst-unique in it.

Comment: JSONStore is also just some local storage, also not particularly relevant to the scenario.

Comment: First of all, MobileFirst is a free suite by IBM used to develop Hybrid Apps. This doesn't necessarily force you to develop both front-end and back-end, deploying the application to a MobileFirst server. You can simply rely on the front-end part and develop the custom native parts for the specific environments. 
Secondly, I am using the JSONStore ocject which is specifically used in MobileFirst.

Comment: Yes, I am intimately aware of what MobileFirst is... I am saying that your question has nothing to do with it, despite your app developed using its tools.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't notice you actually work for IBM and that your specialised in MobileFirst development... that's great! :-D